# problema con gridview en android

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

amigos tengo un gridview con imagenes pero cuando el gridview llena la pantalla del emulador como que reinicia el indice porque bajo con el scroll y ya no sale en orden que tengo en el arreglo miren imagen para explicar mejor:

[image: observen]

[image: aqui ya hice scroll]

este es mi adaptador

```
public class adaptadorImagen extends BaseAdapter {
private Context miContext;

private Integer[] ArregloImagen = {
        R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,
        R.drawable.d,R.drawable.e,R.drawable.f,
        R.drawable.g,R.drawable.h,R.drawable.i,
        R.drawable.j,R.drawable.k,R.drawable.l,
        R.drawable.m,R.drawable.n,R.drawable.nn,
        R.drawable.o,R.drawable.p,R.drawable.q,
        R.drawable.r,R.drawable.s,R.drawable.t,
        R.drawable.u,R.drawable.v,R.drawable.w,
        R.drawable.x,R.drawable.y,R.drawable.z
};

public adaptadorImagen (Context c ) {
    miContext = c;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ArregloImagen.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public int getArregloposicion(int position){return ArregloImagen[position];}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View gridv = new View(miContext);
    ImageView imaView = new ImageView(miContext);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) miContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        gridv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pr, null);
        imaView = (ImageView)gridv.findViewById(R.id.gridview_imagee);

    } else {
        gridv = (View) convertView;
    }
    imaView.setImageResource(ArregloImagen[position]);
    return gridv;
}
```

}

este el xml del gridview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Toca Las Letras "
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/accent_material_dark"
    android:fontFamily="Arial Black"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

<GridView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:columnWidth="120dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:background="#cdcd92"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="1dp">
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo pronto veo raro el código de tu adaptador, prueba a ponerlo de la siguiente manera y me dices:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View gridv = null;
    ImageView imaView = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) miContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        gridv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pr, null);
    } else {
        gridv = (View) convertView;
    }
    imaView = (ImageView)gridv.findViewById(R.id.gridview_imagee);
    imaView.setImageResource(ArregloImagen[position]);
    return gridv;
}
```

Comment: **amigo mil gracias ^_^** , puse el código a como me sugeriste y ya no me da el problema, si pudieras explicarme cual era mi error seria genial pero sino igual mil gracias por tu ayuda.